# Zurb Foundation 5 switches not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, zurb-foundation

I'm using the demo code, I found [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/switch.html) with Foundation 5.2.3 css version

```
<div class="switch">
  <input id="exampleCheckboxSwitch" type="checkbox">
  <label for="exampleCheckboxSwitch"></label>
</div>
```

This is the result:

[image]

Note that the second one is the code I used from Foundation 4, and it still more or less works (The "On" text doesn't display though)

```
<div class="switch small round">
  <input id="test" name="test" type="radio" value="False" checked="">
  <label for="test" onclick="">Non</label>
  <input id="test2" name="test" type="radio" value="True">
  <label for="test2" onclick="">Oui</label>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Not sure what's going on, in the docs it says no javascript is required, the css for the switch is present in foundation.css file

Comment: Tried a quick JSFiddle and same result however I saw this at the bottom of the page on the Doc site:

"Sass Errors? If the default "foundation" import was commented out,
then make sure you import this file: @import "foundation/components/switches";"

Comment: I saw this too, the default "foundation" import uses every component by default. You can comment it out and import components individually. However this only concerns the Sass version, so not relevant to me. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try with newest version of Foundation. Here is my [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/VRJka/9/) in which switches work fine.

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <div class="switch">
                <input id="exampleCheckboxSwitch" type="checkbox">
                <label for="exampleCheckboxSwitch"></label>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Note that I'm using newest [bower-foundation](https://github.com/zurb/bower-foundation) [css](https://rawgit.com/zurb/bower-foundation/master/css/foundation.css).

Comment: Thanks :) I wish they was a simple way to display a label next to the switch... right now it's a pain...

Answer (score 0):

the example in foundation 5 is incorrect, because don't show the label. I searching the example and find this example.

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>
```

And need CSS:

```
.onoffswitch {
position: relative; width: 90px;
-webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
-moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
-o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 30px; padding: 0; line-height: 30px;
font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
content: "ON";
padding-left: 10px;
background-color: #34A7C1; color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
content: "OFF";
padding-right: 10px;
background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
right: 0px; 
}
```

This example is in https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/

Sorry, for my English :), but is the idea.